# How to link pip3 to Python3.4

Tags: pip, python-3.4

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and `pip3 -V` in terminal shows

> pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)

However, `Python3 -V` in terminal shows

> Python 3.4.3

How can I link pip3 to python3.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/usr/bin/pip3` (actually check the path with `which pip3`) and fix the shebang line (the first line of the script): replace

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
```

Comment: hi, but in ' /usr/bin/' this is no python3.4, python3.4 is in '/usr/local/bin', so l replace with ‘#!/usr/local/bin/python3.4', it shows  no module pip

Comment: [Install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) to Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the older version of pip and then reinstall, for Debian based system, use following:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip; sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: Reinstalling for such a simple task? It's Linux, not w32! :-)))